# remove throttle limit in test not working

Tags: php, laravel, throttling, laravel-10

I have a bunch of tests and I need to remove the throttle limit. After many tests I get this error:

> Too Many Attempts.

In file:

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php
```

This is what I tried without success:

- Comment the line `\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class.':api',` from `Kernel.php` file
- Use this code in every test: `$this->withoutMiddleware(\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class)->postJson(url);`

I do not know howto do that.

I forgot to mention: every test I created it extends from a my class that does this:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;


    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->withoutMiddleware(
            ThrottleRequests::class
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, add to `setUp()`  just `$this->withoutMiddleware(\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class)` for the classe that perform that.

Comment: Throttling uses the cache so if you set the cache driver for tests to "array" (which is recommended anyway) you should not have issues with throttling over multiple tests. However you'd still see throttling on a single test if you do too many requests to the same endpoint

Comment: @apokryfos I checked `phpunit.xml` file and I have this `<env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>`. So it should be there, but still I get the error.

Comment: Do you have a single test that is expected to exceed the throttle limit?

Comment: @apokryfos no, I have more than 100 tests, and I get the error almost randomly during the process.